# What will .htaccess code for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I have two SSL,
one for the main domain and other for a subdomain,
What will be the .htaccess code for subdomain by force redirect on https?

**Note :**
Main Domain .htaccess code is

```
Redirection code starts

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Redirection code Ends
```

Comment: What folder is your subdomain pointing to?

Comment: Main            :         mydomain.com
Subdomain :         secure.mydomain.com

Comment: its "Home Directory" at Cpanel

Comment: Just create a `.htaccess` file for your subdomain and put in the same code you have above.

Comment: not working same code